# Historical Death Toll due to Disease

Tags: disease, statistics

I am trying to calculate the number of deaths due to pestilence from 1750-1800,1800-1850,1850-1900,1900-1950,1950-2000, and 2000-2014.

Wikipedia has good information on many: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandemic#Pandemics_and_notable_epidemics_through_history

I started adding up the numbers, but then it becomes very vague for some of the most serious diseases: small pox, measles, tuberculosis, malaria.

Does anyone know where I can get this information? I don't need it broken down by disease necessarily, I'm really just looking for an overall death toll.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a reference request.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Agreed in its present form, but rephrased toward the historiography of finding epidemiology information would be an interesting and IMHO on topic question.

Comment: Would it be better to change the question to "How many people died due to pestilence during these time periods?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a reference request.

Comment: Could we rephrase the question to emphasize methods? This is a good history question phrased in a way that seems to violate the rules. (I think it may be an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question.  What about "How could I design a study to compare death due to pestilence over specific time periods?"